# Processing VBI data in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, iokit, darwin

**Description**: I develop the driver that intended for digitize the analog video (include sound and [VBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval) data such as [teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) and [closed captions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning)). For output the video stream I use `IOVideoDevice` class from IOKit, for sound - `IOAudioDevice`. What class should I use for output the VBI data? Are there an analogs of VBI devices (like /dev/vbi0 in linux-based OSs) in macOS?

**Details**: video stream is a bytes stream (driver doesn't provide video output in the some format, MPEG for example) so I can't encapsulate VBI data into video stream.

```
------              -> video flow -> IOVideoDevice
device -> USB flows -> VBI flow   -> ???
------              -> sound flow -> External driver (IOAudioDevice)
```

MacOS developers forum: [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/324295#324295)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know anything specifically about VBI, but note that the IOAudio KPI is deprecated, and you should be writing Audio drivers in user space instead, via the [core audio server plugin mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013590-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Similarly, I believe the `IOVideoDevice` API is nowadays no longer used, and instead capture device drivers are written as CoreMediaIO plugins. There's not much documentation, but [there's example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) - and don't miss the PDFs ind the "Documentation" folder of the downloadable sample code bundle. For some reason those don't seem to be directly available via the web interface.

Hope that puts you on the right track.